# ERROR  C:\>"Program Files\java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin>keytool -genkey -keystore myStore -keyalg RSA"

Tags: java, keytool

I am getting following error when try to run the above command 
'"Program Files\java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin>keytool -genkey -keystore myStore -keyalgRSA"' is not recognised as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Comment: The effort you put into writing your question is reflected in the effort we spend trying to answer it.

Comment: Check your path??? Also, the quote before `Program Files` seems to be missing its counterpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to command line (`cmd`) in windows (that's pretty obvious).
2. Type this `C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin>keytool -genkey -keystore myStore -keyalg RSA` (see, I removed the quote)`.

Or enclose everything with quotes (and remove the `>`):

```
"C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin>keytool -genkey -keystore myStore -keyalg RSA”
```

Alternatively, use Vineet Reynolds' advice. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is quite obvious from the command you are attempting to run:

```
"Program Files\java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin>keytool -genkey -keystore myStore -keyalgRSA"
```

which is hardly a valid executable. Use quotes only to reference the executable:

```
"C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin\keytool.exe" -genkey -keystore myStore -keyalgRSA
```